# Drop same element to multiple drop areas in Jquery UI

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs, jquery-ui

I have created Angular directive for JQuery UI drag and drop. I have one container on the right side which contains draggable element as here:

Here are two containers on the left that should be droppable areas for the above draggable elements:

```
            <div ng-show="content == 'first'" class="product-large" id="top_board" ng-droppable></div>


<div ng-show="content == 'third'" class="container product-section"></div>
```

Here are both directives, if you are not familiar with angular js, even you can sort it out.

```
    app.directive('ngDraggable', function ($document) {
        return {
            restrict: 'A',
            scope: {
                dragOptions: '=ngDraggable'
            },
            link: function (scope, elem, attr) {
                $(elem).draggable({
                    appendTo: $("#top_board"),
                    revert: 'invalid',
                    helper: 'clone'
                });


            }
        }
    })

        app.directive('ngDroppable', function ($document) {
            return {
                link: function (scope, elem, attr) {
                    $(elem).droppable({
                        accept: '.dragSigners',
                        drop: function (event, ui) {
                            var element = ui.helper.clone();
                            element.appendTo('#top_board');
                            element.removeAttr("ng-draggable");
                            element.removeClass("ng-isolate-scope dragSigners ui-draggable ui-draggable-dragging col-lg-4 col-sm-4 col-sm-6");

   //to make dropped element be draggable in containment after dropping
                            element.draggable({ cancel: false, containment: "#top_board" });

                            element.find("a.delete-btn").css("right", "0px");
                            element.css("margin-bottom", "0px");

                            element.find("a:nth-child(1) > img.thumbnail").css("margin-bottom","0px");


                            //un comment it to remove borders of dropped image
                            //element.find("a:nth-child(1) > img.thumbnail").removeClass("thumbnail");


                            element.resizable({ 
                                resize: function (event, ui) {
                                    ui.element.find("a:nth-child(1) > img.thumbnail").width(ui.element.width());
                                    ui.element.find("a:nth-child(1) > img.thumbnail").height(ui.element.height());

                                },

                                stop: function (event, ui) {
                                    ui.element.find("a:nth-child(1) > img.thumbnail").width(ui.element.width());
                                    ui.element.find("a:nth-child(1) > img.thumbnail").height(ui.element.height());
                                }
                            });

                            element.find("a.delete-btn").click(function () {
                                $(this).closest("div").remove();
                            });

                            element.mouseover(function () {
                                $(this).find("a.delete-btn").show();

                            });

                            element.mouseleave(function () {
                                $(this).find("a.delete-btn").hide();

                            });

                            //element.attr('id', 'mytestId');
                            //$('#mytestId').draggable();
                        }
                    });
                }
            }
        })
```

I know that I am using appendTo: $("#top_board"), which specifies  that the draggable element should be dropped to this element and same in this case, I am using element.appendTo("#top_board") while dropping after cloning this element.

But If I don't specify `appendTo` in **draggable** and **droppable** it I am unable to replicate element in dropable area. 
In short, I am stuck to use only one droppable area. How to sort it out?

Comment: Did you solve this issue dear, kindly help me. I got stuck in same situation. Thanks.

Comment: @Kamlesh please check my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok I solved it by removing `appendTo: $("#top_board")`from `ngDraggable` directive. and replaced `element.appendTo('#top_board')` with `element.appendTo(this)`.
Actually, every `ngDroppable` was appending to `#top-board` div previously.